# Python3 Convert 'CaseInsensitiveDict' to JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, ldap3

I am working on what I assumed would be a simple problem but it has really confused. I am making an AD query in Python using the [ldap3](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) module. This query is returning the data as generator of python dictionaries. When I run the `type()` command against the data it confirms that it is a dictionary.

I need to convert this into JSON so that I can write it to a log file. First, I tried `json.dump(data, file)` but when I do that I receive this error:  `TypeError: Object of type 'CaseInsensitiveDict' is not JSON serializable`

If I try and convert the dictionary to a string first the data is written with quotes and inner fields are left with single quotes so it isn't true JSON - it comes out looking like this: `"{'key': 'value'}"`

Here is what I have:

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as outfile:
    for entry in entry_generator: # Entry is equal to a dictionary of AD attributes
        json.dump(entry, outfile) # I have also tried json.dump(str(entry), outfile) etc
```

I have been searching the interwebs and I see a lot about this issue with the `requests` module but nothing that seems to fix my situation.

With the ldap3 module there is a method `entry_to_json()` which I used in other scripts. It doesn't seem to work here because of the generator, if anyone knows how to make that work again it could solve my problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try transforming the `CaseInsensitiveDict` to a plain old `dict`, like so:

```
json.dump(dict(data), file)
```

Comment: I was actually just trying this exact solution right now. And it is failing - There is only one nested dict so hopefully you're right and that is the issue. I am going crazy with this problem

Comment: -- WOW THANKYOU - I couldn't figure out why I was continually failing, but you were right it was because of the nested dict. What a pain that was, thank you again!!!

Comment: I'm glad to help. I just tried transforming a nested CaseInsensitiveDict (requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict), and to my surprise `dict()` transformed the nested one, too. Neat.

Comment: Major! This is such a clean solution!